# Is it possible to make this code to display 42 years in hours ( including leap years)?

Tags: javascript, leap-year

```
age=42;
days +=(age/4);//leap years
var days= age*365;
var hours= days*24;
var age;
console.log(hours);
```

This code was provided to me by mimo in one of the lessons but I'm not able to resolve this problem. Can you please help me resolve this inconvenience?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here, the code you provided works fine for me

Comment: var hours = age*365.25*24

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, too, had a difficult time with this one.  However, it was also my fault that I jumped into Making a Website project without learning Javascript first.

The answer to this is:

```
var age;
age = 42;
var days = age * 365;
days += (age / 4); *// Leap years
var hours = days * 24;
console.log(hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take leap years into account by multiplying by `365.25`.

Check out this code snippet:

```js
function ageInHours(years) {
   return years * 365.25 * 24;
}

console.log(ageInHours(42));
```

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that you have to know which years it actually was.

Each 4 years there is leap year. You have number 42, which we can write as 10*4 + 2, because the number of 4 years period is our interest. To generalize it, its basically x*4 + 2 and the simples example to imagine how it works is when x=1.

So your example is almost the same as for 6 year period. And we can easily find two examples with different hour rate, based on leap year.

```
2010 - 2016 will have two leap years (2010 and 2014).
2007 - 2013 will have only one leap year (2010)
```

So in order to find correct number, you have to get start year and you have to cycle trough next 42 years. Whenever the year is multiplicable by 4, you add 1 extra day. But be aware, in case of 100 years (i.e. twenty years ago we had 2000), this rule is not used and its same as other years.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get you wrong and you only want to calculate year hours (and there are no specific boundaries for the years like `2000-2042`), you can do as follows for any random year.

Since each year got **365 days** and each day got **24 hours**, You can simply calculate each year hours like this: `year * 365 * 24`. But in order to calculate leap years also, since **leap years happen every 4 years**, you should **divide your desired year by 4** (In order to check how much leap years exist within it) and calculate the floor of it, then the floored number would be the extra days you got, so you should **calculate them individually and sum it up with the specified year.** So the final output should be something like this `year * 365 * 24 + additionalDaysDueToLeapYears * 24`.

Your code finally should be something like this:

```js
function yearToHour(year) {
  const leapYears = Math.floor(year / 4);
  return year * 365 * 24 + leapYears * 24;
}

console.log(yearToHour(42));
```

Answer (score 0):

42 * 8766 = 368172

done.

no javascript needed.